# If web application and SQL Server are on different machines on intranet, can Windows anthentication still be used?

Tags: sql-server

If web application and SQL Server are on different machines(both running Windows) on intranet, can Windows anthentication still be used to access SQl Server or SQL authentication mode need to be used?

Comment: Which user would you like to login to the database: IIS (`YourWebServer\IUSR`) or the web browsing user (`YourDomain\JohnDoe`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web application server will be able to use Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) to access the SQL server if they are both part of the same Active Directory.  If they're not, you'll need to use mixed mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still use Windows Authentication. But how you do so depends on whether the web application forces Windows auth, or if it allow anonymous access and you've set the application itself to connect as a specific domain account.